# Elasticsearch NEST not returning Hits when using c# API ControllerBase in IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, nest

I have been following the [NuSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example) example application and testing by adding an API Controller to return the data instead of the default MVC View. When I return the data using the API controller, the hits - source are populated in the model (the Hits source are being returned from elasticsearch which can be seen in fiddler and the locals inspection), but they are not serialized to the client.
This is the API Controller that I have added to the same project, which uses the same query as the MVC controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class APISearchController : ControllerBase
{        
    private readonly IElasticClient _client;

    public APISearchController(IElasticClient client) => _client = client;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<SearchViewModel> Index([FromQuery] SearchForm form)
    {
        var result = _client.Search<Package>(s => s
            .From((form.Page - 1) * form.PageSize)
            .Size(form.PageSize)
            .Sort(sort =>
    
            //....... code cut for berevity - 
    
        var authors = result.Aggregations.Nested("authors")
            .Terms("author-names")
            .Buckets
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.DocCount);

        var model = new SearchViewModel
        {
            Hits = result.Hits,
            Total = result.Total,
            Form = form,
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(result.Total / (double)form.PageSize),
            Authors = authors
        };

        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Why are the hits - source not being serialised into the returned JSON?

```
    {
  "form": {
    "page": 1,
    "significance": false,
    "query": "test",
    "author": null,
    "tags": [],
    "pageSize": 10,
    "sort": 0
  },
  "total": 3162,
  "totalPages": 317,
  "hits": [
    {
      "explanation": null,
      "fields": null,
      "highlight": {},
      "innerHits": {},
      "matchedQueries": [],
      "nested": null,
      "score": 10538.628,
      "sorts": []
    },
    {
      "explanation": null,
      "fields": null,
      .........
```

I dont have enough points yet to upload an image, but querying the model in the immediate window:

```
? model
{NuSearch.Web.Models.SearchViewModel}
    Authors: Count = 10
    ElapsedMilliseconds: 0
    Form: {NuSearch.Web.Models.SearchForm}
    Hits: {Nest.IHit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>[10]}
    Results: null
    Tags: Count = 0
    Total: 3162
    TotalPages: 317
? model.Hits
{Nest.IHit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>[10]}
    [0]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [1]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [2]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [3]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [4]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [5]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [6]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [7]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [8]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    [9]: {Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
? model.Hits.ElementAt(0)
{Nest.Hit<NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package>}
    Explanation: null
    Fields: null
    Highlight: Count = 0
    Id: "Test"
    Index: "nusearch-04-02-2021-14-25-50"
    InnerHits: Count = 0
    MatchedQueries: Count = 0
    Nested: null
    PrimaryTerm: null
    Routing: null
    Score: 10538.628
    SequenceNumber: null
    Sorts: Count = 0
    Source: {NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package}
    Type: "_doc"
    Version: 0
? model.Hits.ElementAt(0).Source
{NuSearch.Domain.Model.Package}
    AllVersionsUnlisted: false
    Authors: Count = 1
    Copyright: ""
    DownloadCount: 3073
    IconUrl: ""
    Id: "Test"
    Suggest: {Nest.CompletionField}
    Summary: "Test Nuget."
    Tags: {string[0]}
    Versions: Count = 1
```

Edit: Added example json returned to the client:
Edit: Added more detail of model from Immediate window

Comment: What do they look like in the response. show that

Comment: And what was the expected  JSON for hits. The shown update has hits in the JSON.

Comment: I was expecting to see the model.Hits.ElementAt(0).Source data in the JSON data in the browser. The code is the same as the MVC version so the data is passed to the View correctly, but doesnt seem to get passed when using API controller. The code above uses "ActionResult<SearchViewModel>" as the return type, but I get the same issue with IActionResult

Comment: @Nkosi It has Hits in the JSON but not the source in the Hits, even though I can see the data in the model before it is returned, it doesnt get returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the JSON serializer used by ASP.NET (Core) to return JSON does not know how to serialize `result.Hits`, which is a `IReadOnlyCollection<IHit<Package>>`.

There's a few ways to resolve this:

- You could tell the JSON serializer used by ASP.NET (Core) how to serialize `IHit<T>` e.g. `JsonConverter`

or

- pull out the data from hits that is required into a type that the serializer can serialize

or

- capture the response bytes returned from Elasticsearch, by setting `.DisableDirectStreaming()` either globally or per request, and return these

or

- If you have no need to work with the deserialized response, can send the request using the low level client exposed on the high level client to return a string / byte array, and return this directly.